# How to view the Google Docs File menu on my Lenovo tablet?

Tags: tablet, google-docs

I've googled and seen how to restore the File menu to Google Docs. They tend to say to hit the "two arrows in the upper right". For example, the number one hit that pops up (https://www.solveyourtech.com/file-menu-go-google-docs/) says this:

> You can make the menu and toolbar visible again in Google Docs by clicking the downward facing arrows at the top-right of the window.

I don't see any of this on my Android tablet (Lenovo) however. It doesn't seem to make a difference whether I am using productivity mode or not.

Does anyone have any alternative steps on how to get the File menu to appear?

Screenshot of open document:
[image]

Comment: The linked webpage is about Google Docs desktop but it looks that your question is about Google Docs for mobile. Is this correct or you are using Google Docs in a web browser in desktop mode?

Comment: @RubénR I think you are right it would be mobile I am assuming since on a tablet.

Answer (score 0):

The Google Docs app for Android hasn't the same look and feel than the Google Docs web app, some features aren't available.

If you need a feature that is not avaible in the app for Android, try using Google Docs web app. For this, open a web broswer, set it work as a desktop web browser then go to https://docs.google.com.

Related

- [Is there a Google Docs editor for Android that actually works?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/13468/71386)
- [Open Google Docs in Browser](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/219961/71386)

Comment: I tried that in Chrome and Google decided to do what it wanted to do. It opened the doc in Google Docs. SMH